# what consensus client is used while making personal blockchain with geth ( go-ethereum)?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, evm, golang

Modular EVM based blockchain have multiple layers. mainly consensus layer and execution layer.

Execution layer options:
Besu
Erigon
Go Ethereum
Nethermind

consensus clients options:
Lighthouse
Lodestar
Nimbus
Prysm
Teku

my question is: when we make a private blockchain with go-ethereum, what consensus client we use by default, i don't get any option for consensus, and private blockchain just started. where we setup consensus layer ?

Answer (score 0):

Consensus layer with PoS have replaced the PoW consensus alghoritm.

Usually private chains relies on PoA (Proof of Authority) consensus alghoritm, where one ore more nodes are *validators* that can produce new blocks.
PoA blockchains are useful for private networks because you don't need a crypto/token economy to make users able to use them (or you can have your private crypto/token to enable them).
So, usually, you don't need a consensus client on private blockchains, as the consensus is possible by PoA and it's provided by the same client.